# How to link a word comprised of a custom field with another?

Tags: php, custom-field, advanced-custom-fields, links

I want to link content comprised of a custom field(field1_details) using another custom field(field2_link) which is a URL type. `the_field('field1_details')` is text_area field and  `get_field('field2_link')` is a website field (using a [ACF addon](http://github.com/Jeradin/acf-website-field)).

(These custom fields are created using Advanced custom fields plugin)

**Here is the code I am trying in loop.php:**

```
<span class="c_f"><a href="<?php get_field('field2_link'); ?>"><?php if( function_exists('the_field') ) the_field('field1_details'); ?></a></span>
```

Output-

```
 <a href="">The text content</a> ( Doesn't out put the link)
```

**And tried this without the `if`**

```
<span class="c_f"><a href="<?php get_field('field2_link'); ?>"><?php the_field('field1_details'); ?></a></span>
```

**Trying with `the_field` instead of `get_field`**

```
<span class="c_f"><a href="<?php the_field('field2_link'); ?>"><?php the_field('field1_details'); ?></a></span>
```

Output-

`<span><a href="&lt;a href=" http:="" google.com"="" target="_blank">google.com</a>"&gt;This is the test content</span>`

=====================================================

The two custom fields works fine if I use them separately like this:

**Field 1- field1_details**

Output HTML-

```
<div class="field-wrap"><span class="field icon-edit">This is the Text
content</span></div>
```

**Field 2- field2_link**

or without the `if`

```
<span class="link-field"><?php the_field('field2_link'); ?></span>
```

Out put-

```
 <span class="link-field"><a href="http://google.com"
 target="_blank">google.com</a></span>
```

I think I am not using it in a right way. Could any one tell me how to link the field with a URL entered in the another field in loop.php?

Also tell me how would you do it in the functions.php instead of the templates like loop.php

Comment: Why have you included the if clause?

Comment: `if( function_exists('the_field') )` checks if the ACF function exists.

Comment: I'm still unsure why you would check (and not check get_field), but you seem to have some syntax problems. Shouldn't it be `if( function_exists('the_field') ) {the_field('field1_details')}` ?

Comment: I have tried with out the `if`. But no change.

Comment: What is it showing? Can you isolate to see if the problem is the `field2_link` or the `field1_details` function?

Comment: The two fields working fine if I use them separately like this- `<?php the_field('field2_link'); ?>` and  `<?php the_field('field1_details'); ?>`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your URL is blank because you are simply not printing the result. You can either store the URL in a variable and echo it later:

```
<?php $myURL = get_field('field2_link'); ?>
<a href="<?php echo $myURL; ?>">
```

or echo it directly:

```
<a href="<?php ECHO get_field('field2_link'); ?>">
```

Either way you need to use the echo "function" to print the results.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/getting-started/code-examples/#display-a%20field), you should display a field like:

```
<p><?php the_field('field_name'); ?></p>
```

Change your `get_field` to `the_field`:

```
<span class="c_f"><a href="<?php the_field('field2_link'); ?>"><?php the_field('field1_details'); ?></a></span>
```

Comment: I have already  tried `the_field`. But the link is broken. `<?php the_field('field_name'); ?>` is used to publish the field as it is. I don't know how to make it work to link one field with the other field with Website URL.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you are trying to do. Is `field2_link` something like a text field saying http://www.google.com?

Comment: The link field is created using a ACF [addon] (https://github.com/Jeradin/acf-website-field). The fields created using the addon works fine if I just publish it as `<?php the_field('field2_link'); ?>` and the other field `<?php the_field('field1_details'); ?>` separately.

Comment: `field2_link` has multiple inputs. What do you see when you display `<?php the_field('field2_link'); ?>`

Comment: I have updated the question with output for each of my attempt.

Comment: Here is what I see: `<span class="link-field"><a href="http://google.com"
 target="_blank">google.com</a></span>` when I use `<?php the_field('field2_link'); ?>`

Comment: As I see it, the link-field is designed to output the whole html, and so whatever you want to put in `field1_details`. You should be putting into [the field called title](https://github.com/Jeradin/acf-website-field/blob/master/front-end.png) because you are essentially trying to override to functionality that the website field already provides.